# tool for copying files from OneDrive to Google drive directly

Tags: windows, backup, google-drive, copy-paste, microsoft-office

I need a tool to directly migrate all our files from OneDrive to Googledrive. Sharegate, Veeam and Gs Richcopy360 are my final list (all are paid tools) from your experience with that kind of copy, what is the best and if there is a better tool (free and not command line based), please list it

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154). Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then **[edit]** your question accordingly (e.g. what features you need, what price you'd be willing to pay, whether "subscription fees" would be acceptable etc). Thanks!

Comment: Look into rclone maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShareGate, Veeam and Gs Richcopy 360 are great but why not to use the OneDrive desktop app to sync all your OneDrive files to a folder on your computer, then install the Google Drive desktop app and sync that folder to Google Drive?

Comment: good idea for small files